# Can I open a ".pdf" document on a blackberry using java?

Tags: pdf, blackberry, java-me

Can I open a ".pdf" document on a blackberry using java?

If yes, then how?

Comment: java development is not a noun. am i missing something here?

Comment: Aw, be nice. It doesn't look like English is your first language either.

Comment: Do you want to run the PDF app from a java app?

Comment: This answers your question, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335581/open-pdf-doc-ppt-or-xls-on-a-blackberry
just like it solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

theres nothin native in blackberry to load pdf files, but you can achieve that  loading google viewer inside your Browser field, that will do the trick! =D!

```
public ScrLoad()
{     
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://prueba.agenciareforma.com/appiphone/android/elnorte.pdf";                
    add(new BrowserField(url));        
}
```

Google Docs Viewer
http://docs.google.com/gview

Answer (score 3):

The BB doesn't have a built-in PDF viewer.  You can view PDF attachments in emails, but that works with some server-side magic.  I think the best approach is to purchase a 3rd-party viewer and launch that to view the PDF.

Possible viewers include the following.  I've not tried any of these yet.

- http://www.cerience.com/products/reader/
- http://www.slgmobile.com/beamreader.html
- http://www.dynoplex.com/

I think you'd end up using net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager, but I've not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to open a PDF file on the BlackBerry from within a Java program. Since OS 4.5 (I think) the BlackBerry has a built-in PDF reader but it only works when you receive a PDF file via email. Not even stored PDF files on the sd card can be opened.

So, "no" it is not possible to open a PDF in Java.

Except of course, when you write a PDF reader first.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure about Blackberry exactly, but Java 6 SE has a [Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class which can be used to open a `.pdf` file with a program associated with that extension, on that platform.

Try something like this:

```
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
            File pdf = new File(...);  // path to pdf file
            try {
                desktop.open(pdf);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Could not open " + pdf);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: RIM Blackberry is a mobile platform. It's using j2me and own api.