# how to view pdf files in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jpedal

Can anyone tell me how I can show pdf files in blackberry?

I have tried the jpedal library for java-me but, there are some errors.
Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: It's unreadable.
Try code formatting option.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about Blackberries.

It looks like rapc.exe cannot find the base Java libraries. Example:

> Warning!: Implements undefined
>   interface:
>   java.awt.event.ActionListener

Verify that you're passing the correct arguments to rapc.exe.

**Update:**

Assuming jpedal cannot be used on the Blackberry, here's a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726350/can-i-open-a-pdf-document-on-a-blackberry-using-java) that might be useful.

Comment: actually java me doesnt have awt pakages thats why it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a PDF viewer to open PDF files on the device.  PDF files in email and the browser are rendered and displayed using the BES.