# Open pdf, doc, ppt or xls on a BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

How do I open pdf, doc, ppt or xls programmatically on a BlackBerry?

Comment: I want to read the pdf documents through programmatically. Actually we can use the webview in iPhone for reading the document. My question, is there any option or control for reading the pdf doc in blackberry? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean getting the content as string or opening it up for the user?

Comment: I am getting the binary data from the web service.

Comment: I have the same problem.. display these four types of files in blackberry as we do in a webview in iPhone.. any luck Girija ??

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to purchase a 3rd-party viewer and launch that to view the document:

```
String path = "file://SDCard/info.doc";
String contentType = MIMETypeAssociations.getMIMEType(path);
Invocation invocation = new Invocation(path, contentType, null, false, ContentHandler.ACTION_OPEN);
Registry registry = Registry.getRegistry(MyApp.class.getName());
try {
    ContentHandler[] handlers = registry.findHandler(invocation);
    if (handlers != null && handlers.length > 0) {
       invocation.setID(handlers[0].getID());
       registry.invoke(invocation);
    } else {
       Dialog.alert("Error");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Dialog.alert("Error");
}
```